# Find the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{x^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The problem states:

Wherever it converges, find the exact sum of

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{x^n}$$

Using ratio test I know the series converges iff $|x|>1$, but have not idea how to calculate the sum.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks and regards.

Comment: Does it look more familiar if you substitute $x = 1/y$ ?

Comment: @MartinR Definitely. I'm feeling a little embarrased...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow Martin R's comment. Keep in mind that if the function is uniformly continuous, you can interchange infinite sum and differentiation and also $ky^k = y \frac{dy^k}{dy}$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $S = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty na^n$, where $a = 1/x$. Then

$$aS = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty na^{n+1} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (n + 1)a^{n+1} - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a^{n+1} = S - a - \frac{a^2}{1 - a} = S - \frac{a}{1 - a}.$$

Thus $(1 - a)S = a/(1 - a)$, yielding

$$S = \frac{a}{(1 - a)^2} = \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{x}\right)^2} = \frac{x}{(x - 1)^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a useful **finite** evaluation:
$$
1+r+r^2+...+r^n=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}, \quad |r|<1. \tag1
$$ Then by differentiating $(1)$ you get
$$
1+2r+3r^2+...+nr^{n-1}=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{(1-r)^2}+\frac{-(n+1)r^{n}}{1-r}, \quad |r|<1, \tag2
$$ and by making $n \to +\infty$ in $(2)$, **using $|r|<1$**, gives

$$
1+2r+3r^2+...+nr^{n-1}+...=\frac{1}{(1-r)^2} \tag3
$$

If you  multiply $(3)$ by $r$ and set $r=\dfrac1x$, you obtain an answer to your question.