# i dont know how to solve sum of series $n \cdot \frac{1}{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

i need some ideas to solve $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot\left(\frac12\right)^n$$
I prove that the series converges to using ratio method, but i dont know how to find the sum.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{k}{2^k}$?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-evaluate-the-sum-of-n-2-n-from-n-1-to-infinity

Comment: Hint: What do you get if you add $(1/2)^n$ to each term?

Comment: Let $x=\frac12$ in [Find the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{x^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1170897/9464)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with the [usual method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html) for summing a finite geometric series?

Let $\displaystyle S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot\left(\frac12\right)^k= \left(1 \cdot \dfrac 12 + 2 \cdot \dfrac {1}{2^2}+ 3 \cdot \dfrac {1}{2^3} + \cdots + n \cdot \dfrac {1}{2^n} \right)$

Then $\displaystyle \dfrac 12 S_n= \sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot\left(\frac12\right)^{k+1} = \left(1 \cdot \dfrac {1}{2^2} + 2 \cdot \dfrac {1}{2^3}+ 3 \cdot \dfrac {1}{2^4} + \cdots + (n-1) \cdot \dfrac {1}{2^n} + n \cdot \dfrac {1}{2^{n+1}} \right)$

So

$$S_n - \dfrac 12 S_n= \dfrac 12 + \dfrac {1}{2^2} + \dfrac {1}{2^3} + \cdots + \dfrac {1}{2^n} + n \cdot \dfrac {1}{2^{n+1}} $$

$$=\dfrac {1 - (\frac {1}{2})^{n+1}}{1 - \frac 12}-1 + n \cdot \dfrac {1}{2^{n+1}} $$

Thus

$$\dfrac 12 S_n= 2-\left( \dfrac{1}{2^n} \right)-1 - n \cdot \dfrac {1}{2^{n+1}}$$

$$S_n=4-\left( \dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}} \right)-2 - n \cdot \dfrac {1}{2^{n}}$$

So

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\cdot\left(\frac12\right)^k = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n =2$$

Answer (score 4):

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot\left(\frac12\right)^n$$
Then 
$$\begin{align}S&=\frac12+2\cdot\frac14+3\cdot\frac18+4\cdot\frac1{16}+\cdots\\
&=\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots\right)+\left(\frac14+\frac18+\cdots\right)+\left(\frac18+\cdots\right)+\cdots\\
&=\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac12+\frac14+\cdots\right)\\
&=1\cdot 2\\
&=2\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Start with

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n} = \frac{1}{1-x}.$$

Then take the derivative of both sides

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.$$

Multiply by $x$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n} = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.$$

Then plug in $x=1/2.$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{n}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+x+x^2+...\right)'_{x=\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)'_{x=\frac{1}{2}}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}=2$$

Answer (score 1):

Other technique different than the showed in other answers make use of [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) together with particular algebraic rules usually named as [finite calculus](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dgleich/publications/Gleich%202005%20-%20finite%20calculus.pdf).

In this fashion we want to consider the indefinite sum $\sum k x^k\,\delta k$. Using the techniques described in the previously linked PDF we find that

$$\sum k x^k\,\delta k=\frac{x^k}{x-1}\cdot k-\frac1{x-1}\sum x^{k+1}\,\delta k\\\implies\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^k=\left[\frac{x^k}{x-1}\cdot k\right]_{k=0}^{k\to\infty}-\frac1{x-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{k+1}$$

Choosing $x=1/2$ we find that

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\left(\frac12\right)^k=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{(1/2)^k\cdot k}{-1/2}+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1/2)^k=0+2=2$$

Answer (score 0):

use that for the finite sum is $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{2^i}=-2\, \left( 1/2 \right) ^{n+1} \left( n+1 \right) -2\, \left( 1/2
 \right) ^{n+1}+2
$$ compute the Limit for $n$ tends to infinity